Command Pattern or/and Event Handling porgramming paradigm?
I have created a dynamic library that contains all the tools I want my game executable to have. Additionally, I want to create a world editor/tools for my engine to be more user-friendly.
I'm struggling to fully understand what to implement when dealing with mouse/keyboard input handling. I know about the command pattern and how the event handling programming paradigm works, but I'm unsure which one to use in my world editor. I've read the chapter on the command pattern in the Game Programming Patterns book, which is great and this pattern is mainly used on game objects but not on some GUI systems (which could be the case: Command pattern from refactoring.guru). On the other hand, I've watched some of the Hazel game engine series on Youtube (Video here), and it uses the event handling paradigm to manage keyboard input/release, window resizing, mouse input/release...
So, I'm a bit confused about this. Implementing an event system programming paradigm for my GUI world editor seems to be simpler, but at some point, I will implement the command pattern to handle game object interactions. Is it necessary to use the event system programming paradigm?
Thank you.
Note: I will use Dear ImGui for my world editor.

I would suggest you look at what other engines (Unity, Godot, Unreal) do, typically there are two main objectives - First abstract the exact type of input device so people can use any combination of: Keyboard, mouse, gamepad, Joystick or specialized devices for the physically impaired. Second they route the input to multiple in game systems, for example if the user pops an inventory dialog or a chat message box their input is only routed to that system (not to the core game). I think the existing products do a reasonable job, but you might be able to improve it in some way...

Thank you for your response, I will check how game engine works.
